# Create basic php page not working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create new page in PHP(new_page.php), successful created page will be insert into database (create_page.php), but now it is not working, not sure which steps i am missing, any helps are appreciate. Below is my code & screenshots:

Mysql table:

http://i60.tinypic.com/2h3aofr.png

new_page.php

http://i60.tinypic.com/21dmop2.png

```
<?php $host = "localhost";
$name = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "test_son";
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $name, $password, $db);

//Check if connect to MySQL works

if (mysqli_connect_errno()){

    die("Connection to MySql error " . mysqli_connect_errno());
}?>


<?php
function find_all_pages(){
    global $connection;
    $query  =  "select * from pages ";
    $query .= "order by position asc";
    $page_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($page_set);
    return $page_set;
}?>

<h2>Create Page</h2>
        <form action="create_page.php" method="post">
            <p>Subject Id:
                <input type="number" name="subject_id" value="" />
            </p>
            <p>Book name:
                <input type="text" name="book_name" value="" />
                <br/><br/>
            </p>
            <p>Position:
                <select name="position">

                    <?php

                    $page_set = find_all_pages();
                    $page_count = mysqli_num_rows($page_set);
                    for ($count=1; $count <= $page_count; $count++){
                    echo "<option value=\"1\">{$count}</option>";}
                    ?>

                </select>
            </p>
            <p>visible
                <input type="radio" name="visible" value="0" /> No
                <input type="radio" name="visible" value="0" /> Yes

            </p>
            <input type="submit" name ="submit" value="Create Page" />
        </form>
```

create_page.php

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    //Process the form
    $subject_id = $_POST["subject_id"];
    $book_name = $_POST["book_name"];
    $position = $_POST["position"];
    $visible = $_POST["visible"];

    $book_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $book_name);
    $subject_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $subject_id);

    //Perform database query
    $query  = "insert into pages (";
    $query .= " subject_id, 'book_name', position, visible";
    $query .= " ) values ( ";
    $query .= "$subject_id, '$book_name', $position, $visible ";
    $query .= ")";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if ($result){
            //Success will redirect to manage content page
            $_SESSION["message"] = "page was created. ";
            redirect("manage_content.php");
        } else {
            //Failure will redirect to new subject page
            //$_SESSION["message"] = "subject was not created. Please check following possible errors: <br/> "
                    //. " menu name is not blank <br/> visible is not blank";

            //redirect("new_page.php");
            echo "fail " . mysqli_error($connection) ; 
        }
}
```

?>

When i submitted the create page button, error appears:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''book_name', position, visible ) values ( 121, 'how to win influence 1234', 1, 0'

Comment: You're quoting the `'book_name'` column as though it was a string: if you have to quote your column names, use backticks (`) not quotes (').

Comment: `subject_id, 'book_name', position` - remove quotes

Comment: But if you're using MySQLi, please learn to use prepared statements/bind variables

Comment: i have removed quotes but it doesn't helps. the create query works well in Mysql

Comment: If you've removed those quotes, and still getting an error, then it should be a different error message

Comment: thanks mark, i have replace the syntax $query .= "$subject_id, '$book_name', $position, $visible " to $query .= $subject_id .", '" .$book_name ."', " .$position ."," .$visible ; from your deleted post and it's works fine. But the old syntax is working well on the other same php page which makes me confusing :)

Comment: No, it's the list of __column_names__ where you shouldn't have a `'` character.... column names are not string literals, they're column names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have a `'` character in the list of column_names .... column names are not string literals, they're column names. If they absolutely have to be quoted (e.g. if you have a column name that is a MySQL reserved word, then you use backticks(`) not quotes (')

```
$query  = "insert into pages (";
$query .= " subject_id, book_name, position, visible";
$query .= " ) values ( ";
$query .= "$subject_id, '$book_name', $position, $visible ";
$query .= ")";
```

Now please learn about prepared statements and bind variables

Answer (score 0):

There are security vulnerabilities in the way you are creating that query. But to specifically respond to your issue, get rid of the `'`  around `'book_name'`.